# What do you call a mechanism where rotation is transfered in one direction only?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, terminology, flywheels

I have the following to wheels that rotate on the same axis:

[image]

Assuming that they are stuck together, if I rotate the green one the red one rotates at the same speed and when I stop the green one the red one stops.

**I'm looking for the name of the mechanism that makes it so that when I stop rotating the green wheel and I hold it in place, the red one keeps turning.**

PS: I'm building a flywheel (represented here by the red wheel) and the green wheel here is connected with a belt to a crank. I want to make it so that the flywheel keeps turning even when the crank is fully stopped.

Comment: The answers are correct; just thought I'd point out that you can find mechanisms like this in the rear hub of a bicycle and in the connection between a starter motor and the engine of an automobile.

Comment: To add another fun fact along with Carl's, it's this freewheel clutch that gives a bike it's characteristic clicking while the rider coasts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called a "[freewheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freewheel)" or "overrunning clutch".

Answer (score 5):

[Freewheel Clutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freewheel) or
[One-Way-Bearing](http://www.bocabearings.com/bearing-inventory/One-Way-Bearings/19134/3x6-5x6-HF0306KF) or
[Sprag Clutch:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprag_clutch)

[image]

More information:
[Freewheel Clutch Types](http://www.gmnbt.com/free-wheel-clutches.htm)
[Sprag Clutch Information](http://www.gmnbt.com/sprag-clutches.htm)
[Cross+Morse Freewheel Clutch Catalog](http://www.konaflex.fi/datafiles/userfiles/onet/fi/attachments/Freewheel_Clutch.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

[Another solution which is based on spur gears+springs rather than a clutch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nO5nOZVhx74)

[Another solution which is based on spur gears+differentials rather than a clutch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-p8zrvU-cYE)

Found using the keyword "rotation rectifier" (since it's the mechanical equivalent of an electrical rectifier in which alternating current is converted to direct current).

Comment: Both of those mechanisms use ratchets to prevent reverse motion of a shaft. None of this is relevant to the original question.

Comment: I was looking for that term in english, thanks. I beg to differ, as the OP has asked for a way to let the driven part rotate freely when the drive is removed, which is clearly demonstrated at least in the second solution at https://youtu.be/-p8zrvU-cYE?t=2m3s. Though I admit wear and load friction on the drive is not ideal, this is still a solution.